# Oracle query return one row based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I currently have a query that selects multiple rows of data for the application in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    APP_NAME,
    NAME,
    ROLE
FROM APP_PERSON
WHERE APP_NAME='ABCD'
ORDER BY APP_NAME,NAME
```

This returns:

```
 ABCD    Bob    Executive Director
 ABCD    Kim    Director
 ABCD    Sara   Associate Director
 ABCD    Tim    VP
```

What I'd like is for this to return one row, with the person that is the lowest titled 'Role'. The order goes: Associate Director, Director, Executive Director, VP (These are the only options).

So for the example above, the only row I'd like returned is:

```
ABCD   Sara   Associate Director
```

If there wasn't an Associate Director, I'd want Director. How can I create a query that will do this. I'm assuming some kind of DECODE but wasn't sure where to go with it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The clean way (and NF) is to create a table of roles, add a "hierarchy level" column to it, then join.

Comment: If at all possible I'd like to not have to make any changes to the DB. Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: You will regret that within the next 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to approach this question.  I prefer to explicitly join in the priorities, then use `row_number()` to choose the row that you want:

```
select app_name, name, role
from (SELECT APP_NAME, NAME, ROLE,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by app_name order by priority) as seqnum
      FROM APP_PERSON p join
           (select 'Associate Director' as role, 1 as priority from dual union all
            select 'Director', 2 from dual union all
            select 'Executive Director', 3 from dual union all
            select 'VP', 4 from dual
           ) r
           on p.role = r.role
    ) t
WHERE APP_NAME='ABCD' and seqnum = 1
ORDER BY APP_NAME, NAME
```

Comment: Getting the error: 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'. Trying to sort through it, looks like a promising option

Comment: @adaher23 . . . I left out a cuople `from dual`s.

Answer (score 0):

***The order goes: Associate Director, Director, Executive Director, VP (These are the only options)***

I hope the below Query will provide you the Answer.

```
SELECT
    APP_NAME,
    NAME,
    ROLE
FROM APP_PERSON
WHERE APP_NAME='ABCD'
ORDER BY APP_NAME,NAME
where rownum = 1
order by ROLE
```

Comment: It just sorts the values lexicographically, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, this case will with OP's requirement.

Comment: I'd really like to do this in a way that will work no matter what the Role's are. The fact that they are alphabetical might not always be the case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using a common table expresion like so:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    app_name
    ,name
    ,role
    ,MIN(CASE role
           WHEN 'Associate Director' THEN 1
           WHEN 'Director' THEN 2
           WHEN 'Executive Director' THEN 3 
           WHEN 'VP' THEN 4) AS role_level
  FROM app_person
  WHERE app_name='ABCD'
)
SELECT 
  r.*
FROM cte r
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      name
      ,MIN(role_level) AS role_level
    FROM cte rl
    GROUP BY name) ON r.name = rl.name AND r.role_level = rl.role_level
ORDER BY 
  r.app_name
  ,r.name
```

Comment: I doubt whether it will run on **Oracle**